# How to change the color channels of an image in Python?

Tags: python

This is a question that probably should be floating around somewhere here, but I don't seem to find it.

I have this code:

```
import matplotlib.image as img     

img1 = img.imread('./images_32x32/test_1.png')
print("Shape = ", img1.shape) # Output: 32x32x3

img2 = img.imread('./images_32x32/test_2.png')
print("Shape = ", img2.shape) # Output: 32x32x4
```

My problem is in the shape of img2 (`img2.shape`) I would like it to be also 3.

How do I change this?

Comment: Add tag with appropriate `python` library that you use in your code as this is not a common `Python` issue

Comment: May we see your imports please?

Comment: Yes, wasn't aware that this is needed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first image is a RGB image (three values per pixel, red green and blue), the second is a RGBA image (red, green, blue and alpha, for the transparancy of the pixel).

It's just a numpy array, you can slice them:

```
img2_rgb = img2[:, :, :3]
```

Yields a 32x32x3 image without the transparency data.